# getting the average with a while loop

Tags: python

A bug collector collects bugs every day for seven days.  Write a program in Python that keeps a running average of the number of bugs collected during the seven days.  The program should ask for the number of bugs collected each day, and when the loop is finished, the program should display the average number of bugs collected in the week.

I tried running this code that I wrote but it won't get the average of all the numbers inputted by the user. it just takes the first number inputted and divides it by 7. can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
i = 1

while i < 8:

    bugs = int(input('enter the amount of bugs collected today:'))

    average = bugs / 7

    i+=1

print('average amount of bugs collected in a week is:', average)
```

Comment: You should revisit the definition of "average". It is the **sum** divided by the number of elements. Also what you are trying to do is not a _running average_ as you hard coded the eventual length of the list.

Comment: what do you expect this to do `average = bugs / 7` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed adding the `bugs collected today` to the entire collection of `bugs`

You can add an outside var `bugs = 0`

And edit the first line after `while` to:

```
bugs = int(input('enter the amount of bugs collected today:')) + bugs
```

You entire code will look like this:

```
i = 1
bugs = 0

while i < 8:

    bugs = int(input('enter the amount of bugs collected today:')) + bugs

    average = bugs / 7

    i+=1

print('average amount of bugs collected in a week is:', average)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is getting the average from every value in the loop. You should sum all values up and later calculate the average, which is:

```py
i = 1

total = 0
for i in range(7):
    bugs = int(input('enter the amount of bugs collected today:'))
    total += bugs

average = total / 7
print('average amount of bugs collected in a week is:', average)
```

BTW, using for loops in this case is much more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you keep all bugs in a list

```
weekly_bugs = [12, 42, 52, 52, 23, 75, 34]
```

You can find the average easily by using a basic equation.

```
avg_bug = sum(weekly_bugs)/7
```

If you insist to use a **while loop**, you can do as follows:

```
sum_bugs = 0
while(weekly_bugs):
    sum_bugs += weekly_bugs.pop()

sum_bugs/len(weekly_bugs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the wrong algorithmics (already corrected by the other contributors), there is a bunch of non-Pythonic patterns in your code. Consider using *list comprehension* and the `sum()` function.

```
DAYS = 7
bugs = [int(input('enter the amount of bugs collected today:')) 
        for _ in range(DAYS)]
average = sum(bugs) / DAYS
print('average amount of bugs collected in a week is:', average)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
days = 7

total_bugs = 0
avg_bugs = 0
running_avg = list()
for i in range(days):

    bugs = int(input('enter the amount of bugs collected today:'))
    total_bugs += bugs
    avg_bugs = total_bugs/(i+1)
    running_avg.append(avg_bugs)

print('average amount of bugs collected in a week is: {}'.format(avg_bugs))
```